# How to add CSS DIV class to CMS static block? Magento2

Tags: magento2

So I made 3 CMS Static Blocks, which are my footer links.
[image]

How can I add a CSS div class to each CMS static block so I can actually put these footer link blocks **SIDE BY SIDE**?

Would be amazing if someone could help me out! Im stuck with this problem for a few weeks already and didnt find any solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can create parent block with div and call 3 child cms block inside it. In cms block you can add link href by variable {{store url=""}}
To call block cms in cms block use:

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```